# How to write a multi-valued attribute to LDAP "cn=subschemaSubentry" request?

Tags: c#, ldap, ber

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Sammuel-Miranda/LdapServerLib) library (the owner not available) to develop a simple LDAP server; With this library, I cannot use any standard LDAP search filters (from any standard LDAP clients) to find anything because there is no default schema. So I decided to implement `cn=schema` (`cn=subschemaSubentry`) request response for clients.

As you can see, when an LDAP client like `LdapAdmin` or any other LDAP browsers, requests a schema (`cn=schema`), they're looking for something like this:

[image]

So for creating a basic schema, I'm trying to handle the request and write the appropriate response (based on the RFCs) to the callers. I'm trying to create a schema tree and its attributes : `object classes`, `attribute types`, `syntaxes`, ... (I don't know which ones are mandatory or not).

And as you can see, the attribute `Object Classes` has many values like : `person`, `organization`, `room`, ... and I want to create something like this (an attribute with multiple values):
[image]

[image]

My issue is: How to write an attribute with **multiple values** like this in the response stream?

I read the library owner's docs, RFCs and some other docs (about BER encoding, LDIF, ...) but I cannot find how to write a multivalued attribute like this in the proper format.